# Django 1.5 simple form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple form. Whenever I click submit I get a blank page. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am new to django. I have read several questions and answers here but I can't seem to get this solved. Thanks for your help

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, requires_csrf_token, csrf_protect
from django import http
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings

from contact import ContactForm

from django.template import RequestContext, Context

from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

@csrf_protect
def contactview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        #return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.') I edited and removed this
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            message = "The following feedback was submitted from %s  \n\n" % (sender)
            message += form.cleaned_data['message']
            recipients = ['messages@example.com']
            cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(sender)
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients, fail_silently=False)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou/')
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

contact.py

```
from django import forms 

# A simple contact form with five fields.
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

In my template

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}   
    <tr><th><label for="id_sender">Your email:</label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="sender" id="id_sender" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_sender">Name:</label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="id_name" /></td></tr>       
    <tr><th><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label></th>
        <td><input class="text" id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_message">Message:</label></th>
        <td><textarea class="styletextarea" name="message" id="id_message" rows="10" cols="35" /></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_cc_myself">Cc myself:</label></th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cc_myself" id="id_cc_myself" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" /></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Django. I would suggest working through some of the tutorials on http://djangobook.com/ first.

Comment: Thanks @brandon, I looked at the book. I have looked at their example which is very similar to other examples on stackoverflow... still I am getting the same results.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings file? Does the problem occur in local development, or only when the project is deployed, or both?

Comment: Thanks @technivore I have `DEBUG = True` in the settings file. I am deploying this on a server at alwaysdata.com. The system is currently live

Comment: What happens when you do this in local development with `DEBUG = True`? Still just the empty response and no messages in the console?

Comment: I will try this and get back to you... The problem is that the settings on a local Linux box is different from that of the server. I will make the necessary changes.

Comment: @technivore I am working on a local server now. There are no messages to teh console.

Comment: What do your urls.py look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this:

```
return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
```

right after you instantiate the form. Remove that line and execution should continue normally.

Comment: Thanks technivore. I had put that there to test if I would get a "Invalid header found." if anything was posted. I didn't get the message just a  blank page (contact.html)

Answer (score 1):

In urls.py the view functions were being treated as something called "class based views". In order to work with post/get in a class based view, you have to define a method that tells the view class how to process a post request.

In your views.py, however, the view function is not a class based view, it is simply a view function. So I changed the URL in urls.py to indicate its just a function, not a class.

For more information you can read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

```
url(r'^contact/$', contactview, name="contactview"),
url(r'^thankyou/$', thankyou, name="thankyou"),
```